# How do delete all checkboxes in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to delete a checkbox in a certain cell but I need it to delete all checkboxes in a  range I have selected. Following is the code I have that deletes a checkbox in a certain cell.

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="FIELD SERVICES", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Dim CB8 As CheckBox
For Each CB8 In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If CB8.TopLeftCell.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then CB8.Delete
    Next
```

Following is how I tried to alter it to delete cells in the range I need but it only deletes the checkbox in the first cell of the range.

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="FIELD SERVICES", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(8, 0).Select
Dim CB8 As CheckBox
For Each CB8 In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If CB8.TopLeftCell.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then CB8.Delete
    Next
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim f as Range, cbRange as range
Dim CB8 As CheckBox


Set f = Columns("B:B").Find(What:="FIELD SERVICES", After:=ActiveCell, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

if not f is Nothing then
   set cbRange = f.parent.range(f.Offset(1, -1), f.Offset(8, 0))
   For Each CB8 In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
     If not application.intersect(CB8.TopLeftCell, cbRange) is nothing Then CB8.Delete
   Next
end if
```