# macro to delete activex checkbox in the selected range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete the 'ActiveX' check box using below code. However, it is not working. Kindly advise.

```
Sub CheckboxRemove()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim cb As Object

    For Each cl In Selection
        Set cb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Delete()
    Next cl

    Set cl = Nothing
    Set cb = Nothing
End Sub
```

For an example, I have placed these ActiveX check boxes from A1 to F1 cell range. I will select the cells from A1:F1 and when I run this macro then these checkboxes should be deleted. Please advise

Comment: Hi, the answer provided on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509820/how-do-delete-all-checkboxes-in-a-range-of-cells or http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154797 might be of use

Comment: also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/excel-vba-uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton/16818828#16818828) but change the value changing to .Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the checkboxes as Shapes and then check to the position of the upper left hand cell:

```
Sub CheckKiller()
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.Type = 12 Then
        If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Selection) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```